# Emu8086 assembly adder

Tags: addition, emu8086

I'm trying to write an assembly program that adds the numbers (initialized as nums) which are smaller than A0H. However when I run this program it fails to add ANY of the numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

```
     PAGE 60,132
TITLE COOLADDER

    .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 64     


    .DATA
NUMS DB 01H,01H,01H,01H,0A1H,0A1H
SUM DB ?
CC DB ?

    .CODE
MAIN PROC FAR
MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX
MOV CX,6
MOV BX,OFFSET NUMS    
MOV AL,0

AGAIN:  
MOV DI,0A0H      
CMP DI,[BX]
JNA RES

ADD AL,[BX]   
MOV CC,AL
RES:  
INC BX
DEC CX
JNZ AGAIN
MOV SUM,AL
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H


MAIN ENDP
     END MAIN
```

Comment: What do you need help with? What is the problem?

Comment: It is supposed to add all the numbers declared by "num" which are smaller than "0A0H" however instead it adds all the numbers declared in "num".
Through debugging i managed to figure out that the line "CMP DI,[BX]" is not working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data was defined as **bytes** but you are comparing as **words**!

Change this:

```
MOV DL,0A0H      
CMP DL,[BX]
```